# Is it possible to have a multiline placeholder in a textbox ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, placeholder, multiline

```
placeholder="(e.g. 1, (in new line)2,(in new line)3,(in new line)4, ...)"
```

example: textbox will look like:

[image]

How do I continue to next line for this placeholder?

Comment: try this https://forums.asp.net/t/1831337.aspx?Asp+net+TextBox+Placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all set `TextMode` of textbox to `MultiLine`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can do it in your `Page_Load` method by adding `placeholder` attribute and adding newline using `Environment.NewLine` or string literal "`\r\n`" like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "1,"+Environment.NewLine+"2," + Environment.NewLine + "3,");
    //or using \r\n:
    TextBox1.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "1,\r\n2,\r\n3,");
}
```

The output is:

[image]

Hope it will help you..!

Comment: When I save your code to my bin folder, what extension do I use for these types of code?

Comment: Why you need to save it with extension?. Your textbox control is inside your .aspx page and the page_load function is in .aspx.cs page